# C# to sql - date format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table - tblData (Data for Jan.):**

This is how I see the data with `select * from tblData`

```
ID  Tag     Date
1   OB    2014-07-01
2   OC    2014-07-01
3   AB    2014-07-01
```

Trying to achieve the same from C#, but this is not working.

```
DateTime dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim(),System.Globalization.
                  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);

DateTime dtTo = Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text.Trim(),System.Globalization.
                CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);

gridview1.DataSource = objDAL.GetData(dtFrom,dtTo);
gridview1.DataBind();
```

Here's the SQL Server 2008 R2 stored procedure

```
    Alter Procedure GetData
    (
      @DateFrom Date, @DateTo Date
    )  
    As
    Begin
        Select * from tblData
        where date between @DateFrom and @DateTo
    End
```

No rows are returned with the above query, and I believe this could be due to the date formats. How can this be solved? Not sure if it has to be changed in code or in the stored procedure.

**EDIT:**

- The dates in the textboxes are - `08-01-2013`
- In code behind `dtFrom` becomes - `1/8/2013 12:00:00 AM`
- The datatype for 'date' column is just date and not datetime

`GetData` in DAL

```
public DataTable GetData(DateTime dtfrom, DateTime dtto)
{
  var qry = from p in MyDB.GetData(dtfrom,dtto)
            select new
             {
               id = p.id,
               tag = p.tag,
               date = p.date
             }
  dt = qry.ToDataTable();
  return dt;
}
```

The problem's not with the dal code. It executes fine. The row count is 0. So I'm sure its the diff. date formats.

Comment: Can we see objDAL.GetData()?

Comment: What do dtFrom and dtTo contain - and what is the actual data type of the column for Date? Is it DateTime?

Comment: Have you verified the values of `drFrom` and `dtTo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try this in the SP.

```
Select * from tblData
Where
( [date] >= @DateFrom and [date] <= @DateTo )
```

See if it helps.

2) Change your SP to accept DateTime parameters,
otherwise somebody (DAL or below) is probably implicitly 
converting the DateTime values from the UI to Date values.

Comment: Changed it to DateTime as said. The only date in table is Jan 7. The SP works fine when I texted with ~execute GetData '2014-07-01','2014-07-01'~(yyyy-dd-mm). But from webpage, Even if i enter '08-01-2014' & '08-01-2014' (dd-mm-yyyy),in the textboxes, I get all records..!!!

Comment: @Ruby Are you sure in your SP you have AND and not OR in the WHERE clause? Try adding more rows to your table and testing with them. Not just with 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use **CONVERT** function for converting the date as below..

```
Alter Procedure GetData
(
  @DateFrom Date, @DateTo Date
)  
As
Begin
  set @DateFrom = CONVERT(DATE, @DateFrom, 101)
  set @DateTo = CONVERT(DATE, @DateTo , 101)

  Select * from tblData
  where [date] between @DateFrom and @DateTo
End
```

for more date conversation format use ***[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)*** .

Answer (score 1):

When calling your procedure inside `MyDB.GetData(dtFrom,dtTo)` pass `dtFrom` and `dtTo` as strings. For example -

```
//I am assuming you are using SqlCommand To connect to DB
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

OR,

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", dtFrom.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", dtFrom.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

sql server can read this string values and convert them to `date` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check the date format for your query in both C# and in SQL. Sometimes the problem occurs when there's a mismatch of date format, a common mistake is that either of the query includes time and the other does not.